# Submit form with id variable

Tags: php

I have several such forms in the while loop and if I click one button then all the forms on the page submit so I asigned a variable to forms `id="formid-<?php echo $i; ?>"` it changes in every loop and how to target the variable when submitting a form?

```
<?php 

$in = 0;

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)):   

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        $sub = $subscript + 1;
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE users 
                                        SET subscript = ? 
                                        WHERE usernic = ? ");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'is', $sub, $my_username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }   
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="formid-<?php echo $i; ?>"> 
    <h6  class="badge badge-warning font top-8">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Subscribe" id="send">
        <span class="badge badge-light">

    <?php 
         echo $subscript; 
    ?>
        </span>
        <span class="sr-only">Subscribe</span>
    </h6>
</form>

<?php  $in++;    endwhile;  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); } ?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `$subscript` < where is that coming from, or is that not important for us to know?

Comment: Come to that where does `$my_username` come from

Comment: no, it's coming from select above

Comment: How are you handling the id's in terms of the output that is concatenating on the end? Do you know what these numbers are? 1,2,3 and 4 for example?

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like this `<form action="?formid=<?php echo $i;?>" method="post" > `

Comment: dale landry, just numbers on the end of "formid" like formid-0, formid-1

Comment: Right but do you know what they are? Are you privy to how many and what the last number will be? IS it say 1 - 7? This way on the receiving end you can look for each form knowing how many of those id's you'll have

Comment: No, I know that it's for them to be different in every loop

Comment: Okay use a foreach and look for matching keys that match your key value -> `formid`Then for each match run another foreach loop to extrapolate info

Comment: dale landry, maybe you could post the answer with that loop?

Comment: If you post your form examples, I could likely give you code that works.

Comment: not sure what you mean, it's just the same input every time ) with the number of subscribers

Comment: okay submit your form with bogus entries and then do a var_dump and post the array in your question please. If you do not know the number of entries it could have for the ID, then you likely need to find something identifying about the return that can be parse to extrapolate that number and run a loop to recreate the id's

Comment: honestly a better way to do this is to put a hidden input field in the form and place your id there, this way that info will be in your post data array

Comment: ok, thanks, dale landry, I will try this option then )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

First, before the while loop I have this condition:

```
$i = 0;
```

And before the end of the loop I have increment:

```
$i++;
```

Then I placed a hidden input to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

And then I enclosed all code after:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
```

with this if:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['formname']) && ( $_POST['formname'] == $i ) || ( $_POST['formname'] == 0 ) ){ }
```

This way I can targed needed form